# iOS http POST request

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, http

I have an API on the server that I am trying to get a JSON response from. I have used several request tools to simulate a call, and get the correct data back each time. Here is my request setup:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_id=%@&last_sync=%@",user_id, last_sync];
NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL URLWithString:directoryURI];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:directoryURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[post UTF8String] length:[post length]]];
```

The content type is also the same on my simulated requests. There are no errors returned, just no content.

Comment: `@"user_id=%@&last_sync=%@"` this is not POST this is query strings

Comment: I convert the string to data and pass it to the HTTPBody as documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html

Comment: If you have an JSON API then your header should look like this `[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: Did not work. Wouldn't that only matter if I was passing the data as JSON? The result from the server is JSON formatted, but it expects parameters in the regular POST header. My simulated POST requests also work with the current content type.

Comment: yeah , you are right... do you use PHP for the API? you have to make sure that you only echo the JSON, and nothing else

Comment: Yes, I only return the JSON. The same API was also used to create the main listing screens. The results are good in POST simulations, it just wont return anything on the iPad.

Comment: Can you show how you reading the returning post result

Comment: Figured it out. Apparently, unlike the simulators, NSMutableRequest does NOT like when you use a combination of POST variables and a querystring variable in the URL. Moved the variable into the POST body and everything works fine now.

Comment: @TylerKiser Consider posting your comment as a self-answer, so you can mark your question as answered after 2 days.

Comment: @AlexGittemeier Yes thank you. It would not let me do so for 6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently, unlike the simulators, NSMutableRequest does NOT like when you use a combination of POST variables, and a querystring variable in the URL. Moved the variable into the POST body and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I use the AFNetworking library, which takes a lot of the pain out of HTTP comms.

My POST calls are along the lines below:

```
NSURL *nsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"xxxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"yyy"]; // for any header params you want to pass in
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

// If you need to pass any JSOn data to your WS
if (json != nil) [request setHTTPBody:json];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
success:^(NSURLRequest *returnedRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
    ...
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *returnedRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
{
       ...
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using POST method, you have to convert your string into NSData format.

Hope this will help.

Comment: That was in the example code. I figured out the solution but have to wait until I can put it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

URL Form Parameter Encoding

`[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters];
POST http://example.com/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

`foo=bar&baz[]=1&baz[]=2&baz[]=3
JSON Parameter Encoding`

`[[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters];
POST http://example.com/
Content-Type: application/json`


`{"foo": "bar", "baz": [1,2,3]}`